# Why can't I create a Doctrine model named 'Album'

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I'm using Doctrine as ORM in my project but ran against a strange error:

Using following YAML:

```
Album:
  tableName: dpp_album
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    name: string(255)
    description: string(255)
    online: boolean
```

I then generate my models but upon refreshing my page and autoloading the models, PHP serves this error:

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseAlbum' not
>   found in
>   E:\sites\dpp\system\application\models\Album.php
>   on line 13

Strangely enough all my other models are just fine and the Base Classes are found in those cases.

When changing the name 'Album' to something like 'Set' it just works! Ain't that strange?!

So it seems the using 'Album' somehow conflicts, although the error message suggests something else. Change to the plural Albums also doesn't work, anything else is just fine!

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: I would guess that 'Album' is a reserved keyword for that ORM, based on your description.  Perhaps there is a way use a delimiter to circumvent this...

Comment: I thought so too, although a strange one if so! But when searching the docs and sourcecode i could not find anything named 'Album'... :-(

Comment: http://www.google.com/codesearch?q=lang%3Aphp+doctrine+Album&hl=en&btnG=Search+Code Google code finds uses of Album classes too.

Comment: Sure it does, it a common name for a model but it's not included in  standard Doctrine distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the option [generateBaseClasses](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/yaml-schema-files#using-schema-files) is set (default) generateModelsFromYaml() will in your case create a class `AlbumBase` (by default in the subdirectory `generated`) and an empty class `Album extends AlbumBase`. I.e. if `Album` is instantiated `AlbumBase`must already been known or loaded by some autoloader.

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies in the autoloading order of the model classes.

Generated 'Base' models live under the 'models/generated' directory and the other ones in the directory above.

Loading order can't be assured, so sometimes a model gets loaded before the Base model upon which it extends and thus throwing this error.

In my bootstrap file, I have now explicitly included the loading order of the directories as following:

```
Doctrine::loadModels(array(APPPATH.'/models/generated', APPPATH.'/models'));
```

The documentation uses a lot of examples resulting in generated files but does not mention this behavior when talking about bootstrap configurations.

Anyway, happy this is fixed now! :-)